# how to count numbers of different values by row from subsets of dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
            df = read.table(text="ID    L1  L2  L3  L4  L5  L6  L7  L8  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8
            T1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T4  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   1   1   1
            T5  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T6  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T7  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0
            T9  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I want to count "0","1" and "2" by row in the two subsets with columns separately : grep("^L",names(df)) or  grep("^S",names(df)). then create two new columns with the max numbers of values from the two subsets.
the result likes this:

```
            ID  L   S
            T1  0   2
            T2  0   2
            T3  0   2
            T4  0   1
            T5  0   2
            T6  0   2
            T7  0   2
            T8  0   0
            T9  0   2
```

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(dplyr)
mode <- \(x) as.numeric(names(sort(-table(x)))[1])

df |>
  summarize(L = mode(c_across(starts_with("L"))),
            S = mode(c_across(starts_with("S"))), .by = ID)
```

For each `ID`, `c_across` will pass a numeric vector to the user-defined function `mode`, which will return the most commonly occurring number in that vector.

**Output**

```
  ID L S
1 T1 0 2
2 T2 0 2
3 T3 0 2
4 T4 0 1
5 T5 0 2
6 T6 0 2
7 T7 0 2
8 T8 0 0
9 T9 0 2
```

Comment: Nice solution. Was searching for a function like `c_across`.

Comment: @Ludwig, thank you! For the OP, I think this solution works well if you only have a few groupings of columns. For many more column groupings, I left a post on DaveArmstrong's post that could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the easiest way would be to pivot the data longer to put all `S` and `L` values each in a column.  Then, you could group by `ID` and find the modal value within the group for both `L` and `S`.  I made a little function called "modal" that would find the modal value.

```r
df = read.table(text="ID    L1  L2  L3  L4  L5  L6  L7  L8  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8
            T1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T4  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   1   1   1
            T5  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T6  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T7  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
            T8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0
            T9  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
modal <- function(x){tab <- table(x); names(tab)[which.max(tab)]}
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_pattern="([A-Z])\\d", names_to=c(".value")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), modal))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   ID    L     S    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 T1    0     2    
#> 2 T2    0     2    
#> 3 T3    0     2    
#> 4 T4    0     1    
#> 5 T5    0     2    
#> 6 T6    0     2    
#> 7 T7    0     2    
#> 8 T8    0     0    
#> 9 T9    0     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: there is an error: Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 1053680) to match `..3` (size 0).
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: For the OP, this is a good answer and more generalizable than the one I posted. If you change the pattern from `[LS]` to `[A-Z]` and `c(L,S)` to `-ID` this would work for any number of columns that match the pattern A1, B1, ... etc. +1

Comment: @LMc [LS] to [A-Z] gave three columns data with columns names ( ID, number, P), but change c(L,S) to -ID gave error again, Error in `summarise()`:
i In argument: `across(-ID, modal)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `ID` doesn't exist.

Comment: The error `Can't subset columns that don't exist` is due to the fact that `summarize` is being passed a grouped data frame that is grouped by `ID` already. So try changing it to `across(everything(), modal)` instead.

Comment: I'm using R 4.3.0, dplyr 1.1.3 and tidyr 1.3.0 if that matters.  It runs locally without error here.

Comment: I updated the answer to take @LMc's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `aggregate` + `reshape`

```
aggregate(
    cbind(L, S) ~ ID,
    reshape(
        setNames(df, sub("(\\d)", ".\\1", names(df))),
        direction = "long",
        idvar = "ID",
        varying = -1
    ),
    \(x) as.integer(names(which.max(table(x))))
)
```

which gives

```
  ID L S
1 T1 0 2
2 T2 0 2
3 T3 0 2
4 T4 0 1
5 T5 0 2
6 T6 0 2
7 T7 0 2
8 T8 0 0
9 T9 0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `table` on the whole section at once rather than row-wise. This should be faster

```r
row_mode_val <- function(df) {
  tb <- table(c(row(df)), unlist(df))
  as.numeric(colnames(tb)[max.col(tb)])
}

df %>% 
  transmute(
    ID,
    L = row_mode_val(across(starts_with('L'))),
    S = row_mode_val(across(starts_with('S'))))
#>   ID L S
#> 1 T1 0 2
#> 2 T2 0 2
#> 3 T3 0 2
#> 4 T4 0 1
#> 5 T5 0 2
#> 6 T6 0 2
#> 7 T7 0 2
#> 8 T8 0 0
#> 9 T9 0 2
```

Benchmark using a data frame with 10k rows.

```r
f1 <- function() {
  df %>% 
    transmute(
      ID,
      L = row_mode_val(across(starts_with('L'))),
      S = row_mode_val(across(starts_with('S')))) %>% 
    remove_rownames()
}
f2 <- function() {
  df |>
    summarize(L = mode(c_across(starts_with("L"))),
              S = mode(c_across(starts_with("S"))), .by = ID) %>% 
      remove_rownames()
}
# make bigger example
df <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1e4, T),] %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste0('T', row_number()))

bench::mark(f1(), f2(), max_iterations = 1,
     check = all.equal)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f1()         81.3ms   81.3ms   12.3       25.3MB     0   
#> 2 f2()          25.1s    25.1s    0.0398   169.2MB     2.47
```